# Generic way for template argument checks

Tags: c++, templates

I have to following program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define max_dim 100

template<unsigned IDim>
struct Node{};

int main() {
    uint x;
    std::cout << "Input dimension: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    if(x < max_dim){
        Node<x> node;
    }else{
        std::cout << "False Input.";
    }
}
```

which does not compile because the expression `Node<x> node` needs `x` to be a constant value, which it is not. Because I have a limited amount of possiblities what `x` can be (it is limited by `max_dim`) I could of course just use if-conditions or switch-statements, but this would lead to a lot of redundant code (especially because I am doing a bunch of operations for each node).

I am not really able to change the structure of node.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this??

Comment: No matter how you write the code, the issue will always be that all the functions taking `Node<x>` for all possible values of `x` need to be instantiated. That will take a lot of compile time and will likely result in a large binary. Are you ok with that?

Comment: What is that you're exactly trying to achieve?. This feels like an XY problem. That class `Node` has no state anyway and no methods.

Comment: @user17732522 This is a giant project anyway with 1000 of methods of this time. I do not think that compile time is a problem.

Comment: @al3c I tried to create minimal example which includes only for my problem relevant stuff. In my actual code, which is gigantic, Nodeof course has states and methods.

Comment: @wittn Is a C++20 solution acceptable or which version do you support?

Comment: @user17732522 Unfortunaly I think as of now only C++17 is supported.

Answer (score 2):

`std::index_sequence` might help.

Then several ways to select compile code from runtime value (recursion, folding expression with linear number of checks for index), here using array (O(1) access but linear in memory).

```
template <std::size_t I>
void f(/*..*/)
{
    Node<I> node;
    // Your code...
}

template <std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<void(*)(/*..*/), sizeof...(Is)>
make_funcs(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{ &f<Is>... }};
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<void(*)(/*..*/), N> make_funcs()
{
    return make_funcs(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

And then

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Input dimension: ";
    uint x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x < max_dim) {
        constexpr auto funcs = make_funcs<max_dim>();
        funcs[x](/*..*/);
    } else {
        std::cout << "False Input.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. There is no way this  can be done without extra function, right?

Comment: I stumbled across a small problem. If I need to return the node, it is not possible because the nodes have different types, so the array would have to contain functions with different return values, which is not possible to my knowledge. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Extra functions might be replaced by lambda (especially in C++20 which allows to specify template of lambda).

Comment: a function can only return one type (fixed at compile-time). so either return a base class or other type-erasure type, or a `std::variant` of all possible type.

Answer (score 1):

C++17 solution using a helper function, assuming that no return values are required from the `Node<x>` context:

```
#include<utility>

template<typename T, auto... I>
void f(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>, T x) {
    ((x == I && ([]{
        Node<I> node;
        // do something with node
    }(), true)) || ... || (std::cout << "False Input."));
}
    
// in main
f(std::make_integer_sequence<decltype(x), max_dim>{}, x);
```

It is possible to write a solution using only lambdas instead of a helper function, but it is going to look even less clear. The important concept here are *fold expressions* and the `std::integer_sequence` method of introducing template parameter packs into a function. The `&&`/`||`/`(..., true)` construction is essentially just an `if`/`else if` construct written as a single expression relying on short-circuiting behavior of the logical operators.

Comment: This seems to work for my example (I am still kind of confused why there is no more native way to do this). Anyway, in my code I would need to pass one node as a parameter and cast it to its parent class (IDim template is the same for both). Can you tell me how I would alter your code to accomplish this?

Comment: @wittn There exists no more direct way to do this, because it is rarely what one wants to do. As I said it will effectively multiply compilation time and binary size by a factor 100 (assuming you don't run into the compiler's implementation limits). Usually for something like this one would create one class with a dynamic `IDim` instead of passing it as template parameter or one would use virtual inheritance for runtime polymorphism. I don't really understand your question. Do all `Node<IDim>` inherit from the same base class? It might be better to modify the question with more details.

Comment: @wittn: You can put any code into the lambda, as casting node to the base class.